# PostgreSQL read-only user for pg_dumpall

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.4

I'm running a PostgreSQL instance which is used by several related applications, each of which has its own database. For backups I want to create snapshots of the complete data in the instance and I plan on using `pg_dumpall` to do that. The backups are done from another host and should use a separate PostgreSQL user for security reasons.

I am therefore trying to create a PostgreSQL user `backup` who

- can read all data in the instance, both in existing databases/tables and in databases/tables that may be added in the future by other users
- cannot modify anything

So far I have managed the following:

```
-- Revoke default privileges
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;

-- Allow user to connect and use database
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db TO backup;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO backup;

-- Grant read privileges for existing tables
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO backup;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO backup;

-- Grant read privileges when new tables are created
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO backup;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO backup;
```

This works, but only for a single, fixed database. Is there a way to do this for all existing databases and databases that might be created in the future?

I'm currently on PostgreSQL 9.4 and I'm not using any schemas aside from `public`.

Answer (score 2):

This has become much easier with the release of Postgres 14, which introduced the [`pg_read_all_data` role](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1lTTHk-0006rH-HD%40gemulon.postgresql.org).

You can create a new user with permissions to read everything by running:

```
CREATE ROLE backup WITH ROLE pg_read_all_data LOGIN PASSWORD '<password>';
```

Note that even with `pg_read_all_data`, the user appears to be prohibited from reading the [`pg_authid` catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/catalog-pg-authid.html) and for me, `pg_dumpall` still resulted in an error. An additional grant on `pg_authid` did not work either.

However, as long as you can live with Postgres user passwords being omitted from the dump, you may pass the `--no-role-passwords` [option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-pg-dumpall.html) to `pg_dump` and it will work fine.

Comment: The SQL command should be `... WITH IN ROLE pg_read_all_data ...` to add the new role backup as a member of role pg_read_all_data.

Answer (score 1):

Backups from a normal user are a nightmare. If you're using PostgreSQL on Linux, I'd recommend relying on `sudo` (and the `/etc/sudoers` file) to accomplish this, so that a given specific user can `sudo -u postgres pg_dumpall <params>` with specific parameters, so that's all they can do as user `postgres` (and therefore have no write access to the database).

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thanks for the idea! I'm still hoping for a way that doesn't require me to touch the underlying system configuration, although it does seem surprisingly hard to do.